# Oracle REPLACE isn't working - line breaks still happening

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, bi-publisher

I have tried doing the below

```
replace(ITEM_DESCRIPTION, chr(13)||chr(10), '...') as "ITEM_DESCRIPTION"
translate(ITEM_DESCRIPTION, chr(10) || chr(13), '...') as "ITEM_DESCRIPTION"
```

However when I export the output to Excel, I get content in a different cell. When I export to CSV and open it in something like Notepad++ I get the following:

[image: LF character]

I want it all contained within the same cell but this character is causing it to be in different ones

Is there anyway to see what this character actually is when exporting, are there anymore characters I could look at replacing?

I pasted the content into https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php and it said:

[image]

I have since amended by `REPLACE` to the following but still no luck

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(ITEM_DESCRIPTION, chr(13), '...'), chr(10), '...'),chr(13)+chr(10),'...'),chr(10)+chr(13),'...') AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to nest `REPLACE`s (because of whether it is CRLF or LFCR):

```
replace(replace(item_description, chr(13), ''), chr(10), '')
```

Comment: No luck I'm afraid - still getting a break

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `regexp_replace` to replace non-printable characters as follows:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(item_description, '[^[:print:]]', '') FROM DUAL;
```